# Eclipse with CDT not displaying runtime errors to console output

Tags: c++, eclipse, ubuntu, eclipse-cdt

I found one question similar to this, but it did not resolve the issue. Basically, I am trying to use Eclipse with CDT installed for C/C++ development, and no runtime errors are logged to the eclipse console window. Does anyone know of possible solutions to try to fix this issue? I am using the latest release of eclipse juno on Ubuntu 12.04, and all relevant plugins are fully updated.

Thanks.